# onclick having href in a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, href

I want to change page when I click the update/submit button. Here is my submit button code:

```
<td width="8%"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" onclick="??????????"></td>
```

I place a question mark where I want the link/href would be place. Or you can suggest other methods to do that when I click update button it directs me to another php file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No `onclick` needed. `onclick` is for executing JS. This is done by setting `action` attribute for `<form>`.

```
<form method="POST" action="anotherPHPFile.php">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

After clicking on button, you will be redirected to `anotherPHPFile.php`.

Comment: It is correct but not in my coding. Because I have an update db query below that line of code so when I put your suggestion it stops the code reading until there and switches to another php file. How can I update first the database when I click submit button then switches to another php file. Thanks!

Comment: Then change action to same PHP file. After submit, make query and redirect with `header("Location: anotherPHPFile.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this!

```js
function redirect(e){
//If you want to check something here can prevent defualt button action
   // e.preventDefault()

//now do your action.

// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");


// you can also use this line to do similar behavior as clicking on a link
// window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";


}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" onclick="redirect()">
```